# JQuery not working in this program

Tags: jquery, html

I have been trying to give function to drop down list in jquery it's not working at all

function

When I select Yes there should be another drop down list shown up and If I select No then there should be textarea

```
 <h4><label for="NDA">Required NDA to be signed </label></h4>
 <select id="conditions" name="conditions">
<option class="yes" value="yes">Yes</option>
<option class="no" value="no"> No </option>
 </select>
<br/>
  <h4><label for="apptype">App type </label></h4>
  <select name="apptype" class="apptype" id="apptype">
 <option value="games">Games</option>
 <option value="Business">Business</option>
 <option value="Utilites">Utilities</option>
 <option value="Others">Others</option>
 </select>
 <textarea class="txtarea" name="txtarea" id="txtarea" placeholder="Give us the brief gist of your idea"></textarea>';


<input name="Submit" type="button" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised mdi-action-grade" id="submit" >
```

jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#submit").click(function(){
    if($("#conditions").val() == "yes"){
        $('#apptype').hide();
        $('#txtarea').show();

    }
});
});
```

not working please help me

Comment: change Yes to yes  .. you get a value not a text

Comment: i have changed bro but still not working

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9vjke746/

Comment: With the typo resolved Mohamed pointed out this seems to work as I would expect it. Edit your question and add detailed information on what you expect and what currently happens if you believe it isn't resolved.

Comment: yea even @tvanfosson gave me correct what i really needed but it's not working when i include this script in the WordPress

Comment: I wonder why did people give minus for this question

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but I'm guessing that it's a combination of (1) Your title does not describe your problem at all;  (2) using the phrase "not working" once in the title and twice in your question; and (3) you haven't provided a minimal working example -- you have extra markup that has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: 1. Yea Jquery is not working in the program

Comment: Am not worried about your down votes because you're not the only one who gave down votes so no worries... to prove my points respectively 1. Yea Jquery is not working in the program 2. Am sorry to use "Not working" 3. So you think that without giving away html markup you can understand that is a "drop down list"  this is a "text box" and "check box and radio button" as well, the provided example is not example is not working dude that is my problem

Answer (score 1):

You have values set to `yes` and `no` - note lowercase - but you're comparing to `Yes`.  Since the case doesn't match, it won't ever detect when the "Yes" option is selected.

Also, it seems like the trigger ought to be on the dropdown, not the submit button.  You can see a working fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/vn5uz1ma/ Note the changes I made to both the markup, handler, and the CSS assumptions I made.

Comment: @believe_me_am_a_programmer - do you have jQuery included? Did you remember to re-wrap it in the document ready handler on your site (jsfiddle does that for you)? Are there any errors in the browser console? Did you translate all of the changes - code and mark up? The fact that it works in the fiddle, but not on your site means you've missed something in the translation.

Comment: I don understand what's translation, and I wrapped up ready handler and but still not working dunno I have included the file in head as well as in wp_enqueue_script

Comment: @believe_me_am_a_programmer translation = converting my sample code for your specific use case.  It's unlikely that it will work without some modification to fit your site's mark up (or change to the mark up to fit the script).  There may also be conflicts with other code on the page. Are there any errors in the browser developer tools console?

Comment: i dont find any error in the browser, I have converted accordingly to my norm it's pretty fine

Comment: @believe_me_am_a_programmer - there is an error "undefined is not a function" - looks like jQuery is being loaded in noConflict mode. Try wrapping it in an immediately invoked function expression referencing jQuery.  `;(function($) { $(document)... })(jQuery);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67763/discussion-between-believe-me-am-a-programmer-and-tvanfosson).

Answer (score 1):

You have made a mistake choosing selectors

where is working code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        if($("#conditions").val() == "yes"){
            $('.specify').hide();
            $('.txtarea').show();
        }
    });
});
```

URL: http://jsfiddle.net/naveenkumarpg/os2mkz2e/